# How to print value of variable in gtk window?

Tags: user-interface, gtk

I have global variable `maxflow` in my `gui.c` file. I am using `GtkAssistant` for multiple windows. On `page[5]` ,I want to print this value.
Here is portion of my code:

```
typedef struct {
    GtkWidget *widget;
    gint index;
    const gchar *title;
    GtkAssistantPageType type;
    gboolean complete;
} PageInfo;

PageInfo page[6] = {
    {NULL, -1, "Introduction", GTK_ASSISTANT_PAGE_INTRO, TRUE},
    {NULL, -1, "Projects", GTK_ASSISTANT_PAGE_CONTENT, TRUE},
    {NULL, -1, "Profit For Projects", GTK_ASSISTANT_PAGE_CONTENT, TRUE},
    {NULL, -1, "Prerequisites For Projects", GTK_ASSISTANT_PAGE_CONTENT, TRUE},
    {NULL, -1, "Click the Button", GTK_ASSISTANT_PAGE_PROGRESS, FALSE},
    {NULL, -1, "Confirmation", GTK_ASSISTANT_PAGE_CONFIRM, TRUE},
};

page[5].widget = gtk_label_new("OUTPUT\n" "it is time to leave!");
```

This is not continuous code first part is structure, then definition of pages,then I have just shown what I am doing on page[5].
Now I want to display this text and value of a global variable on my window,
can any one suggest changes instead of `gtk_label_new()` what should I use to accomplish my task.
I am very new to gtk.

Comment: Do you want to display `maxflow`'s value in the label? What is the type of `maxflow`? You can create a *string* using snprintf & use that as label i.e. pass that to `gtk_label_new`

Comment: maxflow is an integer. can u show how to do this with an example code

Comment: What is the exact format you are looking for? "OUTPUT\n <maxflow_value> it is time to leave"?

Comment: ya format is: OUTPUT: maxflow is<maxflow value>

Comment: @another.anon.coward can u now provide solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a string with the value of `maxflow` using [`g_snprintf`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-snprintf) or [`snprintf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html) or such function and pass that to `gtk_label_new`. You could try something on these lines:

```
char msg[32]={0};
g_snprintf(msg, sizeof msg, "OUTPUT: maxflow is %d", maxflow);
page[5].widget = gtk_label_new(msg);
```

Hope this helps!